# I'm getting a "missing operator" error in this simple piece of SQL code (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, operators

I have a table named 'book' with a field 'rrprice' that contains several entries of integers.

I want to display the prices that are smaller than the average of all the prices.

```
SELECT rrprice WHERE rrprice<(SELECT AVG(rrprice) FROM book);
```

Comment: Your query look pretty good . . . well, except for the missing `FROM` clause.  I consider that a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT rrprice FROM book WHERE rrprice<(SELECT AVG(rrprice) FROM book);
```

The "missing operator" is likely the FROM clause in the query.